# Rectangle collision detection only working in 1 of 4 directions

Tags: c#, xna, collision

I am making a little game in C#/XNA and I have this problem with collision.

I want to make a normal player movement and instead of just checking if for example the Up key is pressed, it also checks if player `CanGoTop == true`:

```
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && CanGoTop == true) 
{
    // bla bla bla
}
```

I do this for left, right, up, down, and if a boolean is false, the player will not move (there is an `else` statment after those 4 statements of movement that sets `velocity.x` and `.y` to 0)

I made a method inside my Player class:

```
public void RectangleInteraction(Rectangle anotherRectangle)
{
    if (playerRectangle.Bottom <= anotherRectangle.Top &&
        playerRectangle.Top >= (anotherRectangle.Top - playerRectangle.Height) &&
        playerRectangle.Left <= anotherRectangle.Right &&
        playerRectangle.Right >= anotherRectangle.Left)
    {
        CanGoBot = false;
    }
    else CanGoBot = true;


    if (playerRectangle.Top >= anotherRectangle.Bottom &&
        playerRectangle.Bottom <= (anotherRectangle.Bottom + playerRectangle.Height) &&
        playerRectangle.Left <= anotherRectangle.Right &&
        playerRectangle.Right >= anotherRectangle.Left)
    {
        CanGoTop = false;
    }
    else CanGoTop = true;


    if (playerRectangle.Top <= anotherRectangle.Bottom &&
        playerRectangle.Bottom >= anotherRectangle.Top &&
        playerRectangle.Right <= anotherRectangle.Left &&
        playerRectangle.Left >= (anotherRectangle.Left - playerRectangle.Width))
    {
        CanGoRight = false;
    }
    else CanGoRight = true;


    if (playerRectangle.Top <= anotherRectangle.Bottom &&
        playerRectangle.Bottom >= anotherRectangle.Top &&
        playerRectangle.Left >= anotherRectangle.Right &&
        playerRectangle.Right <= (anotherRectangle.Right + playerRectangle.Width))
    {
        CanGoLeft = false;
    }
    else CanGoLeft = true;
}
```

and then in my Game1.cs `Update()` method I use my player instance to call that method there. It works for `CanGoLeft` but for the other 3 bools, it doesn't.

I really don't know why, here are my 4 screenshoots with `InGameMsgs` to help me out, and checking those Messages with my code tells me that the collision logic is good, but something else is wrong. Why does only `CanGoLeft` work then?

[image: CanGoLeft]
[image: CanGoBot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems broken at several points. You should use the `Rectangle`'s method like [`Offset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198289(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) and [`Intersects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464123(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) to check if the target `Rectangle`s would colide. I think this comes close to your intention (assuming `distance` is the value by which you're player moves):

```
public void RectangleInteraction(Rectangle anotherRectangle)
{
    Rectangle down = playerRectangle; down.Offset(0, distance);
    Rectangle up = playerRectangle; up.Offset(0, -distance);
    Rectangle left = playerRectangle; left.Offset(-distance, 0);
    Rectangle right = playerRectangle; right.Offset(distance, 0);

    ConGoBot = !down.Intersects(anotherRectanlge); 
    ConGoTop = !up.Intersects(anotherRectanlge); 
    ConGoLeft = !left.Intersects(anotherRectanlge); 
    ConGoRight = !right.Intersects(anotherRectanlge); 
}
```

(This is assuming you're using [`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx), there are other `Rectangle` structs in .net framework, but your question was tagged [xna](/questions/tagged/xna))